# OCR Extraction from FFmpeg timestamp frame?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I'm doing some precision experiments on trimming and looking to get the textual representation of the timestamp from the frame I export in FFmpeg.

I'm looking for a sort of OCR thing I can run. I wanted to ask the community if FFmpeg supports this natively and if there is a way to extract the timestamp that shows on the frame.

I'm also open to hearing if there are better ways of obtaining this data. Currently, I was just:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -y -i experiment1.mp4 -vf "scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1" -vframes 1 experiment_1_frame.png
```

Then the plan was to write a little node/Python script to OCR the frame, but figured there might be a better way.

Comment: [ocr filter](http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/ocr.htm.gz) exists, but you may have to build FFmpeg from source with `--enable-libtesseract` configuration. In my opinion using a Python script is a better way (you may look for [tutorials](https://pyimagesearch.com/2022/03/07/ocring-video-streams/)).

Comment: Added using Node, took 5 minutes. Thanks for the link.